# Outlook Object Model Save as MHT Set Time Zone

Tags: c#, outlook, timezone, outlook-2010, outlook-object-model

I have a need to save Outlook emails to MHTML (MHT) format. I have a test application that finds one email by EntryID and saves it the MHT format successfully.

My goal is to specify the time zone in which the sent time is displayed. By default, the Outlook object model writes the time to the MHT file using the time zone on the computer that writes the MHT. I would like to specify an arbitrary time zone and daylight saving time observance.

I am using Outlook 2010, Windows XP SP2, Visual Studio 2008 Professional.

I would prefer not to change the time on the processing computer to avoid possible issues with other things that might be happening on the computer at the same time. However, I may have to go that route.

I had hoped to change the time zone of the Application object, but the property `Application.TimeZones.CurrentTimeZone` is read-only. I have not found a Set() method. Attempting to assign to `CurrentTimeZone` results in this error: `Property or indexer 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._TimeZones.CurrentTimeZone' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only`

```cs
//strPst = @"D:\aaa.pst";
//strEntryId = "0000000007840E169496284E947388623A8A9F48C4012000";

//Prepare Session
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application objApplication = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._NameSpace objNameSpace = null;
objNameSpace = objApplication.GetNamespace("MAPI");
objNameSpace.Logon(null, null, false, false);
objApplication.Session.AddStore(strPst);

//Get PST ID
string strPstId = "";
foreach (Store store in objNameSpace.Stores)
{
    if (store.FilePath == strPst)
    {
        strPstId = store.StoreID;
    }
}

try
{
    //Get item
    object xi = objNameSpace.GetItemFromID(strEntryId, strPstId);

    //Get item as MailItem
    MailItem mi = objNameSpace.GetItemFromID(strEntryId, strPstId) as MailItem;
    if (mi != null) 
    { 
        //mi.Display(null); 

        //Get time zone UTC-1200
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.TimeZones tzs = objApplication.TimeZones;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.TimeZone tz = tzs[1];
        //Console.WriteLine(tz.Name);

        //Set time zone 
        objApplication.TimeZones.CurrentTimeZone = tz;

        //Save As MHT
        mi.SaveAs(@"D:\test.mht", OlSaveAsType.olMHTML);

     //...

     }
 }
```

Comment: I've been digging through the reference, and I don't believe it is possible.  The values are stored in UTC, but are converted to the computer's local time zone when retrieved.  You would have to change the computer's time zone programatically and then change it back when you were done.  That has nasty side-effects, and I believe it requires elevated permissions.  You might be better off parsing and rewriting the MHT on your own afterwards.